# Compilation error in nginx on mac

Tags: c, nginx, compiler-errors, osx-yosemite

I am trying to compile nginx on mac os Yosemite,but am getting the following compilation error.

```
/bin/sh: /sbin/ldconfig: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help.Thanks

Comment: Can you provide information as to how you attempted to compile and what version you were compiling? I just downloaded 1.7.9 and ran configure and make; it compiled fine. Do you have Xcode tools installed?

Comment: I am using nginx-1.4.7.I ran configure and then make.I have xcode tools installed